# Parametrization of a lemniscate

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, parametrization

I wonder how to parametrize lemniscate in the following way:

$\gamma : (-\infty, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R^2,$whose image is a lemniscate whose axes of symmetry are $y=x$ and $y+x=0$. The lemniscate is tangent to $x$ axis at $t=0$ and tangent to $y$ axis when $t \to \pm \infty$. When $t>0, \gamma(t)$ lies in the first quadrant and when $t<0, \gamma(t)$ lies in the third quadrant. The lemniscate  is described in [*Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iaeUqc2yQVQC&pg=PA53&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 25.

Here is a parametrization of such a lemniscate whose domain is $[0,\pi/2]$, but I don't know how to modify this example to meet the conditions above.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm this is an interesting question. The best I was able to do was to achieve this: (the animation goes from t=-5..5, but satisfied the conditions from $[-\infty,\infty]$):
[image: Lemniscate Parametrization]
I attempted to first rebrand the function. In the above form it is:
$$\gamma:\left\{\begin{array}\\x=\sqrt{\sin(2t)}\cos t \\
y=\sqrt{\sin(2t)}\sin t\end{array}\right.$$
I attempted to rebrand it into a different parameter which has the following parametrization:
$$\gamma:\left\{\begin{array}\\ x=\frac{|t|}{t}\sqrt{\sin\left(\pi\left(1-e^{-t^2}\right)\right)}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi\left(1-e^{-t^2}\right)\right) \\ y=\frac{|t|}{t}\sqrt{\sin\left(\pi\left(1-e^{-t^2}\right)\right)}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi\left(1-e^{-t^2}\right)\right)\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: A typo was corrected. Can you please indicate tracer  code (Mathematica) for the Lemniscate?

Answer (score 0):

```
r[si_] = 2 Tan[si]/Sqrt[1 + (2 Tan[si])^2]; 
th[si_] = 
 Abs[ArcTan[Cos[si], 2 Sin[si]]/2]; ParametricPlot[{r[si] Cos[th[si]],
   r[si] Sin[th[si]]}, {si, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {Purple, Thick}, PlotLabel -> "Lemniscate_Bernoulii"]
```

EDIT1:

An earlier typo was corrected.

$(r,\theta)$ are functions of tangent angle si. Above code in Mathematica gives the full Bernoulli Lemniscate, however not without a jump plot trace at  si=$\pi$ along $ x=y$. Difficulty here due to self-intersecting Lemniscate curve at origin.

[image: Lemn_Bernoulli]